# Unused import gives me access to the stdout of a signal

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-signals, django-unittest

I just ran into a strange interaction and I'm curious if one of you could explain what's happening:

I'm writing a test, and to start I just created a simple print statement to check if the signal was going off. Here's the test located in `notifications/tests/test_notifications.py`:

```
def test_like_post_save_signal(self):
    """ Testing the signal that is connected to the Like model's post_save. """
    baker.make('core.Like')
```

Here's the signal code I'm trying to test located in `notifcations/notifications.py`:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender='core.Like')
def like_signal_post_save(sender, **kwargs):
    """ Post save signal for Like model """
    print("Something")
```

There's a bit of magic happening behind the scenes, but the goal here is to `print("Something")` every time a Like object is saved.

...

Now, here's what's confusing me. I was able to get it to work, but only after importing a separate function from `notifications.py` into my `test_notifications.py` file.

Here's the import statement: `from core.services.notifications.notifications import print_test`

Why does an import statement of a different function (`print_test`) give me access to the stdout?